# Where i can get cordova 3.2 jar file?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugin-proguard

I have tried using this [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) but am not able to build cordova jar file,

when I run android update project -p . -t android-19
 in my framework directory I get the output:

```
E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework>android update project -p . -t android-15
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
Updated file E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework\proguard-project.txt
It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
please use the --subprojects parameter.
```

Then in the step where I run the command ant jar in my framework directory I get the output:

```
[checkenv] Installed at D:\Program Files (x86)\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Cordova
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 17.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for Cordova...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Android\PhoneGap\cordova-3.2.0-src\cordova-3.2.0\cordova-android\cordova-android\framework\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for Cordova...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with '${build.target}'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] invalid resource directory name: D:\Android\PhoneGap\cordova-3.2.0-src\cordova-3.2.0\cordova-android\cordova-android\framework\bin\res/crunch

BUILD FAILED
D:\Program Files (x86)\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:650: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Program Files (x86)\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:691: null returned: 1

Total time: 2 seconds
```

please help me

Comment: You should recreate project and follow this link step by step (4) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

## Cordova Download & Archives

(1) http://phonegap.com/install/

(2) http://cordova.apache.org/#download

Comment: i have downloaded after building jar file am getting above error

Comment: Recreate your project and follow this link 1) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide 2) http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-  3)http://aerogear.org/docs/guides/CordovaAndroidDevJBDS/an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading from following link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/cordova.htm

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
`E:\eclipse\cordova-android-master\framework>`
open `build.xml` file, change `version-tag: custom` to `version-tag: 1`
save the file.

and run the command

```
android update project -p . -t android-15
```

then run

```
ant clean
```

ant run