# How do i get cordova-3.2.0.jar

Tags: android, cordova

i have already refer these links...

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241637/where-i-can-get-cordava-3-2-jar-file

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html
```

This is my comand prompt o/p :
What should I do...

```
E:\Android Installation\cordova-3.2.0-src\cordova-3.2.0\cordova-android\framewor
k>android update project -p . -t android-18
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because windows is unable to find the program android.bat or android.exe or whatever it is what you need to do is edit your PATH environmental variable and set it to the folder containing the file ,The file is probably at android-sdk/tools/ directory goto your android sdk installation directory/tools copy the path and in the command prompt type`set PATH="<the path you've just copied>"`